# Digital logic/sequential circuit to produce one pulse for every 5 clock pulses

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter, simulink, sequential-logic

I'm working on a problem where I'm trying to design a digital logic circuit (sequential circuit?) to produce output Y given input A:

[image]

So the goal is to produce one pulse for every 5 input pulses.

What I've got so far is to use a 3-bit counter, and then feed their outputs into an AND gate like below (everything is negative edge-triggered):
[image]

My thought was that the output should only be high when (CLK and Qc and NOT Qb and NOT Qa) is high. Does this make sense? I don't have a simulink license so I'm not sure how to check this. Is there a better/simpler way to do this/am I missing something? Any pointers or guidance are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: draw the timing diagram to the second output pulse

Comment: You will need to reset the counter; using JK flip flops can make this much simpler.

Comment: With asynchronous counter, the combination of Q-s will see glitch due to the propagation delay.

Comment: Look for 'finite state machines using JK flip flops'. From a quick look, I can make a synchronous solution using 3 JK devices and 2 2-input AND gates.

Comment: There are plenty of free simulators. For example, [Logisim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYmDpcV0X7k) seems to work well.

Comment: https://www.petervis.com/dictionary-of-digital-terms/divide-by-5-counter-circuit/divide-by-5-counter-circuit.html

Comment: You can do it with one 4017 (Johnson Counter) and nothing else because you have single pin for every count so Output 4 gives you desired pulse then do the reset.

Comment: @Syed but I want the output pulse to have the same width as the input pulse--it seems like a divide-by-5 solution will result in a much wider pulse. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jsotola true, I see it won't work

Comment: Now I see you want pulse high when A is high only so you must add one AND gate. (Y = A AND Q4).

Comment: "Am I missing something": You are missing the reset signal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, my advice would be to use a free logic simulator such as Logisim, which I myself mostly use.

Second, now about your circuit. It is perfectly doable with D flip flops only: three of them are used to count 0-4. Counting state 0, the counter has five states. Finally, a fourth flip-flop whose clock is driven by the main clock delays the reset  by once cycle, which effectively restarts the counter section.

[image]

Be aware however, that this implementation may not work at high frequencies. If your goal requires high speed then use JK flip-flops to make it into a synchronous counter.

Answer (score 1):

Ali:  Your circuit is a good first effort.  All it needs is a way to reset the counter after the desired output pulse ends.  But it can be simplified.

Based on your own timing diagram (thanks for that), because the counter always counts up, you can ignore some of the outputs.  You can see that as long as Qc is low, Qa and Qb can be ignored.  Then, when Qc is high, the desired output signal equals the next clock pulse.  Thus, you can reduce the 4-input AND gate to a 2-input AND gate (Qc AND clk).  This essentially is what is going on in the circuit by Borg.

The advantage is that his circuit includes a way to reset the counter, while yours still needs it to be added in.  This can be done with a differentiator that uses the trailing edge of the Y signal to pulse the counter's Reset input.

Another way to do this is with a CD4017 Johnson counter plus one 2-input AND gate (or two diodes).  As with the Borg circuit, one of the 4017 outputs is used to reset the counter so no more parts are needed for that.